# Дифференциальные уравнения

Tags: python, математика, численные-методы

Здравствуйте у меня есть функция ускорения следующего вида a(x, t), 2 начальный условия x(0) = x0, v(0) = v0. Нужно восстановить функции v(t), x(t) при 0< t <t0.
Я пробовал следующее:
разбивал время на малые сегменты dt =0.01, затем считал , что на малом сегменты движение - равноускоренное, т. е. Δx = v *dt + a * dt * dt / 2, Δv = a * dt. Такие рассуждения привели к неверным результатам.
Также хотел использовать функции для решения дифференциальных уравнений, но т. к. a(x, t) - функция 2 переменных, то ничего не получалось.

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие - нибудь функции в python для численного решения такого дифференциального уравнения?

Comment: Изложите, пожалуйста, не свое видение задачи, а ее точное условие. Откровенно говоря, так не очень понятно. Например, rакой конкретно вид имеет функция a(x,t), Или надо решить задачу в общем виде? Решить дифференциальное уравнение x''(t) = a(x,t)? Написать схему для его решения? Если имеется конкретная функция, можно пытаться решать аналитически. Не решаемо? Можно расписать численное решение, например, Рунге-Кутты. Что именно вам нужно?

Comment: @Harry если выложить задачу как есть, то этот вопрос может попасть под тревогу об "учебных заданиях". Необходимо вместе с ним приложить попытку решения.

Comment: @Acinit Ну так у автора же есть, как он пытался решать. Другое дело, что он попытался открыть Америку через форточку, как говаривал наш школьный физик, когда по незнанию обычного способа решения задачи кто-то начинал придумывать свой, увы, неверный способ...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос рабочий код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В пакете `scipy.integrate` есть целая пачка функций для интегрирования обыкновенных дифференциальных уравнений: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems

Универсальная обёртка - функция [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp)

Пример: предмет подбрасывают вверх, начальная высота 10 метров, скорость 1 метр в секунду. Решение вычисляется для интервала `t \in [0,3]`, используется метод по-умолчанию явный Рунге-Кутты пятого порядка

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np


def a(x, t):
    # Притяжение не зависит ни от высоты, ни от времени
    return -9.81


def diff_equation(t, xv):
    # Первый параметр функции - время, второй - вектор [высота, скорость]
    x, v = xv
    # dx/dt = v, dv/dt = a(x,t)
    return [v, a(x, t)]


x0 = 10
v0 = 1
# Вызов решателя, интервал 0-3 сек, начальные условия, набор 10 точек t от 0 до 3
solution = spi.solve_ivp(diff_equation, [0, 3], [x0, v0], t_eval=np.linspace(0,3, 10))
if solution.success:
    print("t: ", solution.t)
    print("x: ", solution.y[0])
    print("v: ", solution.y[1])
else:
    print("НЕШМОГЛА... ", solution)
```

Результат

```
t:  [0.         0.33333333 0.66666667 1.         1.33333333 1.66666667
 2.         2.33333333 2.66666667 3.        ]
x:  [ 10.           9.78833333   8.48666667   6.095        2.61333333
  -1.95833333  -7.62       -14.37166667 -22.21333333 -31.145     ]
v:  [  1.    -2.27  -5.54  -8.81 -12.08 -15.35 -18.62 -21.89 -25.16 -28.43]
```

Если 10 отсечек вам мало, то поменяйте значение параметра `t_eval`
Например, `t_eval=np.arange(0,3.001, 0.01)` задаёт набор моментов времени от `0` до `3` секунд с шагом `0.01` секунда.

Набор точек в `t_eval` не влияет на точность вычислений, это лишь команда решателю для каких отсечек вывести значения.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень помогли)

Answer (score 0):

**Предварительные** замечания на ваше

> разбивал время на малые сегменты dt =0.01, затем считал , что на малом сегменты движение - равноускоренное, т. е. Δx = v *dt + a * dt * dt / 2, Δv = a * dt.

Идея примерно та, что надо, член второго порядка можно выбросить, оставив

```
dx/dt = v
dv/dt = a
```

И тогда получается на каждом участке просчет как

```
v(t+dt) = v(t) + a(x,t)*dt
x(t+dt) = x(t) + v(t)*dt
```

Получается простейшая [схема Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Дальше зависит от требуемой точности, вида функции etc etc. Может оказаться достаточно этого, может, потребуется более точная [схема Рунге-Кутты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8B), может, что еще...

Вы утверждаете, что приведенная схема у вас не работает - *как именно* она не работает? Может, вы ее неверно реализовали? Без конкретного кода, вида функции и т.д. говорить не о чем. При нечетком ТЗ результат один — ХЗ...

Comment: Да, теперь все ОК. Удаляю коммент.